# C# - Method in thread is not executed

Tags: c#, multithreading

Method in thread is not executed, with thread.start();
Instead when I use thread.join() them method is executed.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[12];
        int temp;

        //_stopRequest = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            temp = i;
            threads[temp] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => test(test1[temp],"start", temp)));
            threads[temp].Start();
            //threads[temp].Join();
        }
```

Could anyone please shed light on this.

Trying to start all threads at the same time

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I suppose that your main thread and application ends earlier before the thread is started. That is why, thread.join solve your problem.

Comment: That's exactly how one would expect threads to behave. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
for(int i=0; i<threads.Length-1; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

at the end of the method. Your threads will start at the same time, and you will wait for their ending. Other variant: set their IsBackground property to true. So, your program will not finish until these threads finish their work.

P.S. In your loop use "int temp = i;", if you want to work with closures. In your case, all threads closure to the same variable temp.